# Extract a list from one sheet to another based on criteria (to be used monthly)

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

I tried VLOOKUPs and they don't seem to do what I want.

I have a data sheet with areas & employee numbers. This data sheets gets refreshed every month due to new starters & leavers.
Then on the same file, I have the info on the data sheet split by area in to separate sheets.
I want these individual sheets to be updated with the information every month.

I cant set the employee list on individual files as the new ones will not be added (& old ones taken out).
I have done a VLOOKUP, but then I have to have a set no of rows on individual sheets & blank ones become #N/A on any additional rows.

Any other suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an Index formula to return all the values that match each region. Let's pretend the following:

- Columns A and B is your master list.
- Columns F and G is your sheet for region "West".
- Columns J and K is your sheet for region "East".

Here's the formula for cell G2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9999, SMALL(IF($F$1=$A$2:$A$9999, ROW($A$2:$A$9999)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

This is an array formula, so you need to press CTRL-SHFT-ENTER after entering the formula to get those curly brackets as seen in the screenshot below. Basically, it's looking up "West" in column A and return a matched value from column B. Drag this formula down as far as you desire, making sure it's far enough to catch new employees that you add to the master list. So if you have 10 employees per region, I would probably drag it down to row 100 for each region. It's wrapped in an IFERROR formula to return a blank value when no more matches are found.

Similar formula for K2.

Adjust your formulas to match your sheet names, columns, etc. Also, remember it's an array formula. When you delete an employee from your master list, the other sheets will automatically update and display clean data without empty rows.

[image]

Comment: Good to hear. If this solves your question, please consider marking as approved, thanks.